# Who will take care of data in Queues in case of a crash

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

we are using a set of Active MQ servers (three ) behind a load balancer .
These configured queues will Persist the Data to a disk (For helping in case of a crash )

My question is Does a developer or MQ admin will take care of these things

Thanks

Comment: You would have to clarify a bit: 'take care of these things'- what things? 'Who will take care of data in Queues in case of a crash' - what part of your system will eventually crash?

Answer (score 1):

If the messages are REALLY important, you might think about replication of them. Once persisted to the disk, replicate them on some other machine also. That is minimum what you should do - not keep messages on the same machine. You should be looking at distributed queues:

[Distributed Queue](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-distributed-queues-work.html)

Who's responsibility it is? Well, you companies, the people who design and build the solution. It's everyone's. If you can do it (and I am sure you can try at least), then go ahead.

IMHO in your case the ActiveMQ part needs to be done by developer, and the replication on the Server side by an admin, not necessarily an MQ Admin, but the admin. May be set up a cron job to replicate the needed data?

Cheers,Eugene.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is as secure as the weakest element of safety. You can loose messages when one server crash (disks). You will not be able to recover messages so You should take care for safety in app.

ActiveMQ can be more safe (but slower). Replicated Message Stores
Look here http://activemq.apache.org/clustering.html